# Could not open modal window dynamically using Angular.js/Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an issue. I am trying to open one pop-up window dynamically using Angular.js and Jquery but its not opening. I am explaining my code below.

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='View' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" ng-click="viewSearchDetails(133);">
<div class="modal fade" id="viewdetailssec" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewexamplelabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-repeat="ind in indUserDetails" ng-if="indUserDetails.length >0">
 <div class="modal-dialog fyndspacemodalsec" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title pull-left" id="viewexamplelabel">View Details</h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.viewSearchDetails=function(userid){
    $scope.indUserDetails=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.allUserInfo,function(obj){
      if(obj.user_id==userid){
        $scope.indUserDetails=obj;
        $("#viewdetailssec").modal();
      }
    })
  }
```

Here I need to open the pop up window while if statement will execute but its not opening at all. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I checked and executed the code on my machine. Modal popup is opening. May be it is not passing the if condition criteria. First, try to open popup modal outside loop and condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to see here:

- you need to push the selected object in the array as
  `$scope.indUserDetails.push(obj)`
- Make sure you have all the dependencies set for `bootstrap js and css`
- Also, you can set the `data-target="#viewdetailssec"` in the HTML itself for the modal reference.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.allUserInfo = [{
    user_id: 131,
    name: "xyz"
  }, {
    user_id: 132,
    name: "xyz"
  }, {
    user_id: 133,
    name: "xyz"
  }, {
    user_id: 134,
    name: "xyz"
  }]

  $scope.viewSearchDetails = function(userid) {
    $scope.indUserDetails = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.allUserInfo, function(obj) {
      if (obj.user_id == userid) {
        $scope.indUserDetails.push(obj);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='View' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewdetailssec" ng-click="viewSearchDetails(133);">

  <div class="modal fade" id="viewdetailssec" role="dialog" ng-if="indUserDetails.length >0">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="ind in indUserDetails">
          <p>{{ind}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $("#viewdetailssec").modal("show");
```

Comment: No.still same issue is there.